# Can we get a synonym from [language] to [languages]?

Tags: discussion, support, meta, synonym-request

[language](/questions/tagged/language) is the not-yet-synonymized singular of [languages](/questions/tagged/languages), less used though used in the same way.

Can someone please add the appropriate synonym?

Answer (score 2):

These tags should not be made synonyms. They appear to be two different tags (although frequently used incorrectly/interchangeably). One is for the use of language and the other is for questions about non-English languages. I'm not sure which should be which, but first I would add/correct the tag wikis to properly explain the use case, and then we'll need a bit of a tag cleanup to make their usage consistent.

But as a side note, even if these tags meant the same thing, I wouldn't recommend adding a tag synonym to handle pluralization as such. Tag synonyms were designed to be used when there are two *completely* different words used for the same concept. Think "cars" versus "autos". But for something like this, text completion would help the user pick the correct usage. <kbd>l</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> → [language](/questions/tagged/language).

Comment: If that is so, there's a considerable amount of cleanup neccessary, as well as writing of a second, clearly different, tag-wiki. Also, even if tag-synonyms are not *meant* for unifying singular and plural versions of the same concept, that is still expected, as such is observed.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently these tags are supposed to [reflect 2 very different concepts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246384/can-we-get-a-synonym-from-language-to-languages/246401#246401), although that intended usage is not clear from the current usage nor from the tag wikis.

Since tags names should not invite confusion (otherwise you end up with a jumbled mess like we have now), both should be renamed to eliminate the confusion.

As such, I propose:

[language](/questions/tagged/language) ---renamed to---> [appropriate-language](/questions/tagged/appropriate-language) ([credit to Mureinik for this phrasing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246384/can-we-get-a-synonym-from-language-to-languages/246401#comment806617_246401))

[languages](/questions/tagged/languages) --renamed to---> [foreign-languages](/questions/tagged/foreign-languages)

I am not crazy about the naming of "foreign languages" as that has a decidedly pro-English context but I could not think of another short choice of words that would accurately describe the concept.

Likewise, it looks like there is a 3rd use case mixed in there and that is programming language.  As that [tag already exists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-languages), we just need to retag those questions.

And the original tag names should be made synonyms of the new tag names once everything has been retagged appropriately.

Comment: Perhaps if you also consider the tags [tag:non-english-speakers] and [tag:english], that might spark some ideas. At least, they should be clarified and cleaned up at the same time.

Comment: @Deduplicator good call.  All of them could be pulled under a single tag to cover anything with languages